# How to set PivotX to the right edge of a view? (Not for animation)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

```
View.setPivotX(float value)
```

At first I thought this method takes a "percentage" as an input, in which `0f` stands for the left edge, and `1f` stands for the right edge.

After testing, however, it is not. And from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPivotX(float)), although not very clear, it looks like we need to pass in an absolute location in terms of pixel.

I have tried `view.setPivotX(view.getRight())` but the result is not what I expected. The view becomes out-of-screen instead.

So... How can I correctly pivot a view to its right edge? (Same for bottom edge, for PivotY)

P.S. Please note that I am not asking for the purpose of performing an animation, I simply want to reduce the size of a view by a certain ratio.

Comment: view.getWidth() ?

Comment: indeed, but first make sure `getWidth()` returns anything != 0, i mean "layout phase" has been already done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Left top:

```
view.setPivotX(0);
view.setPivotY(0);
```

Left center:

```
view.setPivotX(0);
view.setPivotY(view.getHeight() / 2);
```

Left bottom:

```
view.setPivotX(0);
view.setPivotY(view.getHeight());
```

If you want to set pivot in `Activity` `onCreate()` or `Fragment` `onCreateView(...)` method (when views doesn't measured yet) you can do this:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            view.setPivotX(0);
            view.setPivotY(0);                

            //some other view transformations

            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Haha I hate myself that I can't figure this out. By the way, just a warm reminder for the others, getWidth() and getHeight() to a GONE view will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin version:**

```
// top left
view.pivotX = 0f
view.pivotY = 0f

// bottom right
view.pivotX = width.toFloat()
view.pivotY = height.toFloat()

...
```

In Activity's `onCreate()` or Fragment's `onCreateView(...)` you can access width and height simply by using `doOnPreDraw` extension from [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx), i.e.:

```
view.apply {
    doOnPreDraw {
        pivotX = width.toFloat()
        pivotY = height.toFloat()
    }
}
```